# Difference between the usage of 準備 and 予習

Tags: word-choice

## 日本語

この二つの言葉の意味の違いを教えていただけませんか。

「準備」と 「予習」 の意味は同じですか。違うなら、どんな時にそれぞれを使いますか。

## English

Could someone tell me the difference between these two words?

Are the meanings of 準備 and 予習 the same? If they are different, when should each be used?

Comment: 参考までに、明鏡国語辞典によりますと：`『よしゅう【予習】まだ習っていないところを前もって学習すること。↔復習』`   ---  生徒/学生が prepare for lessons することを「予習」と言いますが、先生/教師の場合は「予習」ではなく「(授業の)準備」と言います

Comment: @Chocolate 先生方もよく「予習する」という言い方をしますよね。おどけた表現かもしれませんが（笑）

Answer (score 6, accepted):

予習という言葉の意味は「レッスンの準備」だと思う（preparation for a lesson）。一方で準備というのはもっと一般的に使用される意味がある　（preparation;  setup;  arrangements;  provision;  reserve）。

例えば、

1. 旅行の**準備**は済みましたか。＝ Have you made all the arrangements for your trip?
2. 明日の**準備**で忙しい。 ＝　I'm busy getting ready for tomorrow.
3. 彼女は朝食の**準備**をしている。＝　She is getting breakfast ready.
4. 私はめったに世界史の授業の**予習**をしません。＝ I rarely prepare for the world
   history　lessons.
5. 彼は**予習**した。 ＝　He prepared his lessons.
6. 私は英語の授業の**予習**にあまり時間をかけない。＝ I don't spend much time preparing for English classes.